# Typescript classes that are functions but also have properties

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to implement the following interface:

```
export interface Foo {
    (): void;

    bar: number;
}
```

Using classes?

This is the closest thing I could figure out:

```
var foo = function () { } as Foo;

foo.bar = 5;
```

Comment: The best way of determining if something is possible is to try it.

Comment: if you think about it.. that's what a class gets compiled to ;) Also. the handbook is a very good place to search for questions such as these.

Comment: In my answer I assumed that what you really want is some object that implements that interface, not necessarily a class. Is that correct?

Comment: I am trying to find the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not completely sure, I think this is not possible using classes without some serious hacks. I think this interface syntax is actually for supporting external library typings, where in many cases such constructions exist.

What you actually refer to in your sample code, is `static` members of a class. I mean a class with a public constructor and some static members is exactly this construction. But static members cannot be declared in interfaces (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a class do this, but you can use type aliases and intersection types to do something like this:

```
// Define the type of your objects
type Foo = { (): void } & { bar: number };

// You could have a factory method to create instances
var fooFactoryMethod = (func: () => void, bar: number) => {
  var foo = func as Foo;
  foo.bar = bar;
  return foo;
}   

var myObject = fooFactoryMethod(() => { console.log("Hello world") }, 23)

// Or just creating them manually
var myObject2 = (() => { console.log("Hello world") }) as Foo;
myObject2.bar = 45;

// Now you can use it like this
var func = (arg: Foo) => {
  arg();
  arg.bar = 34;
}
func(myObject)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Define%20the%20type%20of%20your%20objects%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%20()%3A%20void%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20You%20could%20have%20a%20factory%20method%20to%20create%20instances%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20fooFactoryMethod%20%3D%20(func%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%20bar%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20foo%20%3D%20func%20as%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20foo.bar%20%3D%20bar%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20foo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20myObject%20%3D%20fooFactoryMethod(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22Hello%20world%22)%20%7D%2C%2023)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Or%20just%20creating%20them%20manually%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20myObject2%20%3D%20(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22Hello%20world%22)%20%7D)%20as%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myObject2.bar%20%3D%2045%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Now%20you%20can%20use%20it%20like%20this%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20func%20%3D%20(arg%3A%20Foo)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20arg()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20arg.bar%20%3D%2034%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20func(myObject))

Comment: Modules behave differently than classes though.

Comment: @user3233089 Sure, but do you need classes here? What is your use-case?

Comment: I need to use class specific attributes: creating multiple instances of for example.

Comment: @user3233089 Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

All classes are functions when they get compiled into js.

```
export class FooClass implements Foo {
    bar: number;

    constructor() {
        this.bar = 1;
    }

}
```